# Set Div to move below another Div as screen size shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have two Div's, the left one is a sidebar of sorts (but it does not extend the full height of the screen), and the right one is the content Div that should occupy as much of the screen as possible and collapse/move underneath the sidebar as the screen shrinks. Right now I have the sidebar set up how I expect it to be, but the Content Div begins to overlap the Sidebar as the page shrinks and does not move below.

I have tried different position: parameters (fixed,absolute,relative) different width/min-width values, as well as different values for float. I have everything in html styling right now for simplicity. The css files that were being used seemed to be interfering with functionality so I attempted to override them via styling directly within the HTML.

```
<body style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; min-height: 80%; min-height: 50vh;">
<h3 class="text-center"> Title </h3>
<div class="SideContainer" style="background-color: green;position:absolute;left:0; top:80; bottom: 400;width: 20vw;min-width: 200px;max-width: 300px;padding: 3px;">

<div style="background-color: red;width: 100%;">Keys</div>
<div style="background-color: blue;">Error Box</div>
<div style="background-color: grey;border: none;width: 100%;border-radius: 3px;">File Menu Button</div>
<p> Enter Display Name</p>
<div style="background-color: yellow;">Name Box</div>
<p> Users Viewing </p>
<div style="background-color: orange;">User box</div></div>
<div class="ContentContainer" style="background-color: gold;position: relative;float: left;left:20vw; top: 25;width:80%;min-width: 400px;margin-right: 3px;padding: 8px;">
<div style="background-color: purple;border: 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;line-height: 2.6;padding: 3px;margin-bottom: 6px;">Doc Title</div>
<div style="background-color: maroon;min-height: 150px;border: 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;padding: 3px;">Doc Content</div></div><body>
```

Content div should shrink, and at a certain point, move below the Sidebar div.

Comment: I suggest you separate out your CSS into a separate file and use media queries to change styles according to viewport width.

Comment: if your have your `.SideContainer` set to position absolute, then it is "out of the flow" of the document. It is absolutely positioned and other content will not affect its position (push it out of the way on different screen sizes for example) so you can get overlap.

Comment: You should considering to use `@media(max-width:586px){ /*css here*/ }` changing 586 with the wished value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; min-height: 80%; min-height: 50vh;">
<h3 class="text-center"> Title </h3>
<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">
    <div class="SideContainer" style="background-color: green;left:0; top:80; bottom: 400;width: 20vw;flex-grow: 1;padding: 3px;min-width: 200px;max-width: 300px">

        <div style="background-color: red;width: 100%;">Keys</div>
        <div style="background-color: blue;">Error Box</div>
        <div style="background-color: grey;border: none;width: 100%;border-radius: 3px;">File Menu Button</div>
        <p> Enter Display Name</p>
        <div style="background-color: yellow;">Name Box</div>
        <p> Users Viewing </p>
        <div style="background-color: orange;">User box</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ContentContainer" style="background-color: gold;float: left;left:20vw; flex-grow: 4;top: 25;margin-right: 3px;padding: 8px;min-width: 200px;">
        <div style="background-color: purple;border: 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;line-height: 2.6;padding: 3px;margin-bottom: 6px;">Doc Title</div>
        <div style="background-color: maroon;min-height: 150px;border: 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;padding: 3px;">Doc Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<body>
```

I got your code working using **Display:flex**, it's a good idea to also separate your code into html and css and use classes references in the HTML. There is a lot of benefits to this including easier to maintain, cleaner, and also makes it easy to follow etc.